# In stochastic filtering, can observations depend on lagged observation values?

Tags: kalman-filter, filter

Say I have a latent state like
$$ dX_t = dW_t $$
and observations like
$$ dY_t = f(X_t - Y_t)dt + dZ_t $$

Can I get filtering estimates of $X_t$ using a standard Kalman filter framework despite the observation dynamics depending on $Y_t$?  In the references I found, it seems like that is not possible.  Is there a more appropriate method for this problem?

Comment: with a nonlinear f probably not. in general any lagged observed values, being deterministic at time t, can be integrated into the formulas in an additive (linear) way.

Comment: Ok thanks. So with linear f, a standard Kalman filter could work?   Is there any approximate method that would work for non-linear f?